# 3.3V to 5V logic level shifter with 3.3V microcontroler board and 5V arduino sensor

Tags: microcontroller, current, current-limiting, level-shifting, bidirectional

[image]

I would like to use logic level shifter like the one above.
3.3V logic level would be connected on NodeMcu 3.3V microcontroller board pin, while 5V level would be used for Arduino sensor.
What troubles me is the current flow.
I don't think I understand properly current flow.
When 3.3V logic level is LOW, will some current flow back towards 3.3V microcontroller pin through R1 or through R1 and R2 combined towards 3.3V pin?
Should I worry about that?
I would appreciate if someone could help me understand a bit more about current flow in this circuit?

Comment: For what usage the level conversion is needed? Note that this level converter is not suitable for all purposes, but only special cases where for example bi-directional translation is needed for relatively slow signals (e.g. for 400kHz I2C).

Comment: Philips application note (https://cdn-shop.adafruit.com/datasheets/an97055.pdf , page 10) explains this circuit in details, and what you should worry about (spikes, isolation) when using it.

Comment: I would like to use it for ultrasonic HC-SR04 sensor readings. I am aware that this translation has limitation on lower freq, but for this purpose should be ok I would say. I am also interested in translation on higher freq for different project, I didn't find suitable materials so far. But that is another story, not related with this topic

Comment: @V.V.T The document is useful in general, but I did not find exactly what I am looking for. I am interested understanding of currents for this circuit when LOW logic level is on low side of the circuit. If it current is not specified in document, does that mean it is not something I should worry about?

Comment: Note that this circuit is meant for open collector devices on both sides. It won't work when either side is actively driven high.

Comment: Citing this pdf, page 10, section 2.3.1, 2nd item: '* State 2. A 3.3 V device pulls down the bus line to a LOW level. ...  the bus line of the “Higher voltage” section is also pulled down to a LOW level ... the bus lines of both sections become LOW at the same voltage level.' It seems Philips does not worry about currents through pullups, do they?

Answer (score 1):

"I would like to use it for ultrasonic HC-SR04 sensor readings."

IME an SR04 can be triggered by a 3.3V pulse, and the output can drive a resistor divider that dives the 5V down to 3.3V. So you should get by with just 2 resistors.