# Can a 3.3v logic i2c be directly connected to 5v logic i2c

Tags: i2c

So can a 3.3v mCu directly communicate via i2c to a 5v mCu ? the buss will be pulled to the lower voltage 3.3v. And since i2c protocols involves just sinking current is what makes me think it will work

Comment: This depends on the specific devices... I'm also not sure why you say that "I2C protocols involves just sinking current"? I2C is very much a voltage-level protocol...

Comment: @RonBeyer, they probably mean that the 5-V device won't be driving 5 V onto the bus because it has an open-drain driver rather than totem-pole.

Comment: Maybe, if the 3.3V device is 5V tolerant. You really need to say what exact devices you are using.

Comment: the answer to https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/539731/3-3v-to-5v-logic-level-shifter-with-3-3v-microcontroler-board-and-5v-arduino-sen may be relevant to this question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends what the \$V_{ih}\$ minimum level is on the 5 V device. You can look this up in the datasheet. If it's lower than 2.7 V or so, then you should be okay.

This is a plausible scenario if your 5-V device uses TTL logic levels rather than CMOS. However, the [I2C Standard](https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/user-guide/UM10204.pdf) defines the input levels roughly as CMOS levels, so this would require a non-standard device.

With standard-compliant devices it won't be possible, because \$V_{ih}({\rm min})\$ is \$0.7\times V_{dd}\$ and \$0.7\times 5\ V = 3.5\ V\$.

As pointed out in comments, if your 3.3-V device has 5-V-tolerant inputs, you may be able to connect the two devices together directly with the pull-ups to 5 V instead of 3.3 V. Again, check your datasheets. Again this would not be compliant with the I2C standard, but many microcontrollers are not strictly compliant.

Comment: The other way is more likely to work - many 3.3V MCUs have 5V tolerant IO pins, especially for I2C pins.

Comment: D'oh! My bad, sorry.

Comment: @Justme I do apologize for not providing an IC as this is just a random question i cant get out of my head. So the next time i ever encounter a situation where i need to connect 3.3v and 5v i2c logics, check if the 3.3 version i2c pins are 5v tolerant before adding a level shifter circuit?

Answer (score 3):

Don't build a product to sell like you described, but if you are playing around with a home project, it will work well enough to get by.

I use MSP430 MCUs with 3.3V IO with 5V I2C LCD displays. I had to remove the 5V pull-ups on the LCD PWB and add my own 3.3V pullups. Works fine.

Worst case CMOS logic high is 70%, but a typical part switches close to 50%. 70% of 5V is 3.5V, 50% is 2.5V.

Comment: Beware, some 5V devices have I2C ports with Schmitt trigger inputs that _do_ have a higher threshold voltage.

Comment: Its not even a home project, let alone a product to sell. Just a random question i cant get my mind off. I do apologize i was not able to specify an IC